# The Potential Application of Gravity Manipulation As a Power

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, physics, gravity, super-powers

Given that a person is granted the power of manipulating gravity, or namely alter the gravity of any object they touch (including themselves), what would be some potential applications of said power? In addition to this, what could be some potential limitations, in terms of stages of progress the individual would have to advance through to gain access to what would be otherwise be considered a stronger application of said power?

How would you go about placing limitations or strengths on this character? (I've also heard of the concept of gravitational waves and suppose they could be altered if they were touched to the person who had it).

Edit : The gravity manipulated would be referring to the gravity exuded by an object.

Comment: What do you mean by "alter the gravity of an object"? What do you visualize as the _functional_ limits of gravity manipulation (not necessarily _magnitude_)?

Comment: [Hard Magic](https://grimnoirchronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Hard_Magic) beat you to it. There's a short story in the same universe (featuring the same main character, who is a gravity manipulator) which you can read for free [here](https://www.baen.com/categories/free-library/free-short-stories-2011.html).

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding Armorien, take our [tour] and refer to our [help] for guidance as to our ways. Enjoy the site.

Comment: Biggest problem: they have to touch it. If the character is simply simulating mass, there's no flying, no repulsing. They would likely die quickly trying to do anything cool - they'd crush themselves into a ball, and at best have at least a hand ripped off, more likely get sucked into a singularity. But for really BIG things, they could destroy the planet, ablate the atmosphere, and in crushing their world, possibly reverse the inflation of the universe in the process. I would have directional control of gravity, despite all the paradoxes that would involve. That's where fun abilities happen.

Comment: Given the world setting in which his body is able to tolerate substantial damage (as a result of superhuman durability which I did not mention, apologies) do you think the consideration given to balancing destructive capability and power would be more interesting, or do you think directional control of gravity would still be better?

Comment: What is powering up this gravity manipulation, what are the limits of it? Can this person touch the Earth and nullify its gravity?

Comment: @DWKraus, if this person can *reduce* an object's gravity (although, what does that mean? Are they altering its *mass*?), they can do lots of neat things. Or if they only increase an object's gravity by a modest amount (say, double), I believe that still allows some interesting things.

Comment: @Matthew I was assuming it was the gravity generated by the object, but it isn't exactly clear. But yes, if you could reduce the effect of gravity on an object (without reducing it's mass) there's a lot of potential. certainly super-jumping (still limited by mass and air resistance) but (slowly) moving heavy objects, making objects immovable. It also matters a lot if the effect persists after they stop touching and how long after. Even better if they can reverse gravity. Interesting buoyancy potentials, too.

Comment: 3 votes to close this question as too story-based and not even one comment justifying this decision. How can the OP fix it if they have no idea what is wrong?

Comment: Ultimately I do apologize, I'm not quite sure how the forum works and if this would seem to be too unspecified and inconclusive as a question.

Comment: @DWKraus Sorry for the lack of clarification, what I was referring to was the gravity generated by the object as pointed out by Matthew.

Comment: @Alexander But yes, what is powering this gravity manipulation would be in essence, magic of some form, the limits of it would be that the objects wouldn't be able to experience more/less then double its gravity and they would be able to reduce the gravity of the earth to some extent.

Comment: @Armorien does it mean the person can increase Earth gravity to 200%, but can not decrease it all the way to 0%?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, to be more clear, they would be able to decrease it to maybe 50%.

Comment: @Armorien: if you want ideas for how your gravity manipulation could work, please research the Knights Radiant from the Stormlight Chronicles, particularly the Windrunners. I believe you'll find it helpful.

Comment: @Alendyias Thank you very much for the suggestion! I will do.

Answer (score 1):

**Every action has an equal and opposite reaction.**

This is just a basic concept from Newtonian physics and you can kind of adapt this.

Your characters can control as much force as they like, *but* their own body feels the opposite change in force they cause on something else.

So anyone using their powers to fling a car away is going to need to be able to do that with their body as well, because it's the same effect on them.  Use your gravational powers to lift something up - you better be able to do that with your arms without snapping your back or you'll just hear "snap" when you try.

Now you can adjust the amount of "feedback" they get to let them do as much as you want, but ultimately they are limited by their own need to survive intact.  In essence this is kind of like telekinesis limited by it's effect on the person doing this.

**Applications.**

Lift.  Fling.  Sink. Move.  Stop. Etc.

Things you can't do : anything that's going to do damage to you because of the equal and opposite forces you'll be feeling.

Answer (score 1):

**Most superpowers aren't seriously explained for a reason**

Gravity is not unlike a magnet... a magnet with only one pole. It eminates (if it does anything at all) from that pole in a reasonably uniform sphere and afects everything it touches. I believe (but I could be wrong) that it doesn't matter if something is in the way. The gravity of a sun touches every planet in its system in the same way even when those planets are lined up.

And your superhero can change that.

- Your superhero's body (or, perhaps more accurately, whatever physiologically rationalizes the existence of the power, like a new organ or something) automatically comprehends the *limit* of the power. In other words, gravity cannot be increased such that the superhero themselves will be hurt by it. This is similar to building muscles. Yes, we can strengthen them, but ultimately unless we humans do something incredibly stupid, our muscles will not allow us to do something that will tear muscles or ligaments or break bones. Neither will whaterver it is that allows your superhero's powers. He/she cannot modify gravity such that the superhero him/herself will be hurt without serious (and often debilitating) concentration to force the body past that limit.
- Gravity pulls things toward it. Period. Humanity has no evidence of real "anti-gravity" or a gravity that pushes something away. Remember, like a magnet with only one pole, and everything is attracted to it as if all other gravitational sources are always opposite poles of all gravitational sources (let the headache begin). So, what can you do with it? Gravity is most commonly thought of as the center point of a sphere, meaning that whatever you choose to modify, everything will be pulled more quickly or less quickly toward that modified point. Make a fist and increase gravity by 1,000X? Expect everything in a mile radius to crush the superhero. Maybe even start a small black hole. Same fist but reduce the gravity to zero? Yup, nothing happens because everything is affected by the planet, too. Maybe the mosequito has a bit of trouble landing on your knuckle and biting you.
- What could  be interesting if if you start playing with geometric shapes. What happens if you uniformally increase the gravity of a bridge? All the water is sucked up around it like a giant cylinder. What if you made a human-sized box and made the inside 2G and the outside 0G? That might make a pretty cool prison because an escapee might have no leverage at all to help them out of the box. Or maybe I want to reverse that, 0G inside and 2G outside... yeah. I like that better!

Personally I think gravity manipulation as a super power is kinda weak because gravity itself is fairly limited. It pulls in one direction. Period. Unless you start playing with magic (which is what most super powers are... magic. Not science.)

- If the superhero embues a rope with 2,000G gravity (remember the mass of a rope, folks, it's not very high.) and should the superhero have the strength to whip that sucker around, then he/she would be pulling stuff along with the rope — except that all your superhero is manipulating is gravity and the superhero's mass is also in play. That means that after the rope has picked up, oh, 50-100 kg worth of dirt, leaves, and frisbees, the hero can't swing it anymore.

Yeah. Science and superheros really don't mix. Superheros are all about magic masquerading as science. Otherwise they're not much fun.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a weight loss business. People come in, get touched, and walk out weighing less. Considering just how much money is spent each year on weight loss, this would be a highly profitable business.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity, as we perceive it on our planet, has two components -- it's strength and it's direction.  For us poor earthbound beings, the acceleration due to gravity is roughly 9.81m/s<sup>2</sup> and it's direction is towards the centre of the earth.

As you start to leave the planet the force pulling you back may change, and once you leave the planet entirely, there may be all new things that gravity begins to pull objects towards.  The answer assume one is on the planet of origin

I've no idea how to explain why a person could manipulate gravity on touched objects, but I can provide thoughts on what to do with that power.

#### Power Progression

Using those two parts in mind, my thought is that the first step is that gravity on an object can be changed in proportion to what it is already experiencing, from a near-zero value to the limit of what the user's body can tolerate.  The lower bound prevents accidently yeeting oneself off the planet and the upper bound prevents a horribly messy death.

There are four potential avenues for upgrading the power which can be invoked individually or simultaneously.

- **Increase Limits** -- Lower the lower bound and/or raise the upper bound of what gravity can be set at.  In theory, negative gravity should repel an object from the planet, potentially yeeting it into space
- **Set a Fixed Value** -- Your user can set one's gravity to a specific quantity as opposed to a proportion of the current gravities
- **Change Direction** -- Change the direction that gravity is attracted to the object.  Instead of the centre of the earth, change their gravity to attract them to a different part of the planet, or perhaps a specific object.  It would be one way to stick someone to a flagpole or wall.
- **Add Gravity Point** -- Set a point in space or an object as something that things are attracted to.  This doesn't eliminate normal gravity, but it does mean that multiple forces will be playing on each other.

#### Power Applications

Now the fun part -- how do you your power for fun and/or profit?

First of all, you have some manner of athletics.  From the moment you launch yourself off the ground, you accelerate according to gravity -- that 9.81m/s<sup>2</sup> thing again.  Reducing your personal gravity should, in theory, enable you to jump higher and climb easier as you have less of a pull to the ground.  None of this allows you to survive a fall or the landing better so be wary of that.

On the inverse, increasing one's gravity could mean that more force is being applied to them all over, making it potentially a plausible strength training tool.  I doubt it would be healthy for extended periods if such a training even works.

In a combat sense, there might be value in changing gravity on your opponent to throw off their timings as the same force may not yield the same results under a different personal gravity.  I wonder if you lowered your opponent's gravity right when you punch them, if they would fly farther?

For somebody less interested in personal athletics or combat, I observe that gravity is part of the Rocket Equation.  Plausibly, if you could lower the gravity of an entire rocket, you could partially, if not fully, free it from the tyranny of the rocket equation.  This means your gravity manipulator could help immensely with space infrastructure.

Considering one might need some serious sci-fi tech, or magic, to have this kind of power, another avenue might be alien accommodations.  Some aliens might be accustomed to a different gravity than out planet's and a person that could manipulate the gravity of a being could manipulate an alien's gravity to match their home world's.  Does nothing about the potentially lethal environment, but it is one less problem to factor in.

#### Advanced Power:  Flight

I put this separately because while all the above is about manipulating the raw amount of gravity, this is about manipulating both the direction and magnitude of gravity on a fluctuating basis.

In theory, if you can fine-tune both the amount and direction of your personal gravity and alter its direction just right, then you should be able to recreate some semblance of flight.  It likely would not be as pretty as using conventional means to fly (or a flight superpower), but it would be plausible.

In a less complicated way, some manner of deployable wing and a large drop might be a good first step into flight, or assisted falling as the case may be.